# How to download the text along with tumblr images?

Tags: images, tumblr

There are several tools to download images and videos from a tumblr. But I haven't found even one that downloads the text along with the image (I am NOT talking about text posts). Example: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn4BE.jpg).

Is there any way to download the text (along with the images, preferably as metadata)?

Comment: You could just download/save the portion of the HTML you want.

Comment: @MC10 Yeah, that's an option. Anything more graceful than that?